# Hazard Distribution

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Let $Y$ be a random variable denoting the age at which a piece of equipment fails. In reliability theory, the probability that an item fails at time $y$ given that it has survived until time $y$ is called the *hazard rate*, $h(y)$. In terms of the pdf and cdf,
$$h(y)= \frac{f_Y (y)}{1− F_Y(y)}.$$

Find $h(y)$ if $Y$ has an exponential pdf.

I don't understand what this question is asking for please help.

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**
Let $Y$ have exponential distribution. What is the pdf $f_Y(y)$ and the cdf $F_Y(y)$? The hazard rate is defined by
$$
h(y) = \frac{f_Y(y)}{1-F_Y(y)}.
$$
Plug both into this definition and simplify.

Comment: understood thank you for the help